# Why does while(true) loop just run once - Java

Tags: java, swing

I read serveral similar questions but those answers couldnt help me with my problem:
This is a while(true) loop for a tictactoe game and should run the whole time. But it only runs once I tested it **EXCEPT** I type a sysout somewhere in the loop...(not in one of the if statements):

*Doesn't work like this:*

```
void winCheck() {
    while(true) {
        if(buttons[0].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[1].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[2].getValue() ==  1) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[3].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[4].getValue() ==   1&& buttons[5].getValue() ==  1) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[6].getValue() == 1  && buttons[7].getValue() == 1  && buttons[8].getValue() ==  1) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[0].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[3].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[6].getValue() == 1 ) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[1].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[4].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[7].getValue() ==  1) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[2].getValue() == 1  && buttons[5].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[8].getValue() == 1 ) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[0].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[4].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[8].getValue() ==  1) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[6].getValue() == 1  && buttons[4].getValue() == 1  && buttons[2].getValue() == 1 ) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[0].getValue() == 2  && buttons[1].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[2].getValue() ==  2) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[3].getValue() == 2  && buttons[4].getValue() == 2  && buttons[5].getValue() ==2  ) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[6].getValue() ==2   && buttons[7].getValue() == 2  && buttons[8].getValue() ==  2) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[0].getValue() == 2  && buttons[3].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[6].getValue() == 2 ) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[1].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[4].getValue() == 2  && buttons[7].getValue() == 2 ) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[2].getValue() == 2  && buttons[5].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[8].getValue() == 2 ) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[0].getValue() == 2  && buttons[4].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[8].getValue() == 2 ) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(buttons[6].getValue() == 2  && buttons[4].getValue() == 2  && buttons[2].getValue() ==  2) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        } else if(
                    (buttons[0].getValue() == 1 || buttons[0].getValue() == 2) &&
                    (buttons[1].getValue() == 1 || buttons[1].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[2].getValue() == 1 || buttons[2].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[3].getValue() == 1 || buttons[3].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[4].getValue() == 1 || buttons[4].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[5].getValue() == 1 || buttons[5].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[6].getValue() == 1 || buttons[6].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[7].getValue() == 1 || buttons[7].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[8].getValue() == 1 || buttons[8].getValue() == 2)) {
            dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Draw..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Start.main(null);
        }
    } 
}
```

*but it works like this (sysout at the end) so it runs the whole time not just once*:

```
void winCheck() {

        while(true) {


            if(buttons[0].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[1].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[2].getValue() ==  1) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);


            }

            else if(buttons[3].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[4].getValue() ==   1&& buttons[5].getValue() ==  1) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[6].getValue() == 1  && buttons[7].getValue() == 1  && buttons[8].getValue() ==  1) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[0].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[3].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[6].getValue() == 1 ) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[1].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[4].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[7].getValue() ==  1) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[2].getValue() == 1  && buttons[5].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[8].getValue() == 1 ) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[0].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[4].getValue() ==  1 && buttons[8].getValue() ==  1) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[6].getValue() == 1  && buttons[4].getValue() == 1  && buttons[2].getValue() == 1 ) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Crosses win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }



                else if(buttons[0].getValue() == 2  && buttons[1].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[2].getValue() ==  2) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[3].getValue() == 2  && buttons[4].getValue() == 2  && buttons[5].getValue() ==2  ) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[6].getValue() ==2   && buttons[7].getValue() == 2  && buttons[8].getValue() ==  2) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[0].getValue() == 2  && buttons[3].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[6].getValue() == 2 ) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[1].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[4].getValue() == 2  && buttons[7].getValue() == 2 ) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[2].getValue() == 2  && buttons[5].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[8].getValue() == 2 ) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[0].getValue() == 2  && buttons[4].getValue() ==  2 && buttons[8].getValue() == 2 ) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                Start.main(null);

            }

                else if(buttons[6].getValue() == 2  && buttons[4].getValue() == 2  && buttons[2].getValue() ==  2) {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Noughts win..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);



                Start.main(null);


            }

            else if(

                    (buttons[0].getValue() == 1 || buttons[0].getValue() == 2) &&
                    (buttons[1].getValue() == 1 || buttons[1].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[2].getValue() == 1 || buttons[2].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[3].getValue() == 1 || buttons[3].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[4].getValue() == 1 || buttons[4].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[5].getValue() == 1 || buttons[5].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[6].getValue() == 1 || buttons[6].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[7].getValue() == 1 || buttons[7].getValue() == 2) && 
                    (buttons[8].getValue() == 1 || buttons[8].getValue() == 2)

                    ) 
                {

                dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Draw..", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


                Start.main(null);
            }

            System.out.println();

        } 
    }
```

***I just don't get why :/ Tried many things but didn't work.. Answer would be so cool..***

*by the way even stranger: It works without System.out.println() in debug mode but not in normal mode or exported as jar...*

Comment: Use a debugger, that would be so cool.....

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Try to find which line is causing issue

Comment: Yeay thats what I did for hours lol..

Comment: What does `dispose()` do? Are you in a `JFrame` that is set to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` ?

Comment: By the way forgot to say its working while debug so I cant find the problem but its not working normally or after exporting

Comment: Yeah i'm in the JFrame but its not even coming to that point and why is it working with a System.out.println() at the and in debugging mode then? :/

Comment: Note -- this is a Swing application, meaning you shouldn't even have this `while (true)` loop there at all. You're thinking in terms of linear console type applications, and when creating event-driven GUI applications, you must change your mind-set into thinking and coding in an event-driven way. Instead of a `while (true)` loop, you check for wins whenever the program's state changes, meaning, you'd check for win any time a move occurs. So get rid of this loop, use observer pattern with listeners (perhaps an ActionListener, or a MouseListener depending on the code) and your problem is solved.

Comment: Extending from the great comment by @HovercraftFullOfEels. There's a **ton** of redundancy in your code. Getting rid of that might make debugging easier.

Comment: *"while(true) loop for a tictactoe game and should run the whole time"* - Why? That sounds counterintuitive, not to mention really dangrous

Comment: Ye guys your right and I can completly understand you and I get the point but I don't get why its just running once without a Sysout thats my problem ^^ But you are of course right..

Comment: @javaprobs: If I were an instructor and a student came to me with this code, I would tell him not to bother debugging it because it is not worthy of being debugged as it is convoluted, confusing and poorly written. I tried going through it to see if I could spot the bug, but it's a holy mess. Sorry but this code should be discarded, and your time would be much better spent to re-start your logic with cleaner much easier to debug code.

Comment: k @HovercraftFullOfEels will do it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check do you have winner every time when someone click on any JButtons (I thought on X and O buttons).

So you don't need while loop you can improve IF to be more simples.

Comment: Thank you for your improvement but it didnt answer my question at all bcause I had no problem running my app at all.but I dont get this "bug"

Answer (score -1):

There may be some problem in your second class that ends the game. A simple typo, most likely. Might want to find a program such as BlueJ that has the capability to execute one class at a time.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, plus, the OP mentions that he's run his code in debug mode, suggesting that he's already using an IDE, so not sure what the BlueJ recommendation will achieve.

Comment: @ DaveyDaveDave This question is almost 1 year old. I hope his problem solved by this time.

Comment: @eldo Yea I was looking for unanswered questions for the archeological badge :P

Answer (score -4):

When you make it like this, the while() would run forever.
You should make a boolean and name it for example gameover.

```
boolean gameover = false;
while(!gameover){
//your gameloop
if(yourgameovercondition){
gameover = true;
}
}
```

Comment: I had this before it doesn't change anything and the loop is supposed to run forever thats why I changed it but it didnt work before either

Comment: This is also completely inappropriate for a Swing GUI program.